# Turn on/off nest from remote android application

Tags: java, android, rest, firebase, nest-api

Is there a way we can turn on/off a nest learning thermostat from firebase or rest?

Firebase is more preferred option on android/java as it is mentioned in the API documentation. but Nest themselves have not clearly mentioned how we can switch on/off a thermostat. the official nest app can do it but I'm writing my own and I can't seem to figure out a way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot power the thermostat off using the Nest API or if you go through Firebase. You can change the `hvac_mode` to one of the [states listed on the API reference](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api#hvac_mode).

Values (limited to this list):

- heat
- cool
- heat-cool
- off

I'm assuming off is the state you're referring to on the "official" app. If you really want to power the system off entirely, I would suggest using a controller like the [Arduino](http://arduino.cc). You can include the Arduino in your Android or Firebase work. I have an Arduino interfaced with my Nest that draws outside air when inside/outside temperatures are right.

Comment: @Mr.Noob what did you decide to do?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe Nest extends the ability to power off thermostats through the developer API.

The official Nest app will have more features than the API offers. If Nest extended the ability to turn off the thermostat from the API it could definitely lead to some abuse.

This is from [their developer website](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/how-to-thermostats-object):

> We offer two Thermostat permission types, Thermostat read and Thermostat read/write

All the read/write permission allows for is writing to `is_fan_timer_active`, `target_temperature`, and `hvac_mode`.